# Run time error in java code

Tags: java

Hello I am a newbie to java and i am going along alone from a book, wherein there is a code called pharseomatic, which basically selects a random words from a list of word list and prints to the output.

The is as below :

```
public class phraseomatic{
    public static void main( String[] agrs){

            String[] wordlistone = { "Hello ", "whats up ", "How ", " U doing " };
            String[] wordlisttwo = { "I am ", " Am Interseted ", "Learning ", "Java" };
            String[] wordlisttre = { "C sharp ", "C plus plus ", "C and Unix ", "Linux "};

            int wlen1 = wordlistone.length;
            int wlen2 = wordlisttwo.length;
            int wlen3 = wordlisttre.length;

            int rand1 = (int) ( Math.random() * wlen1 );
            int rand2 = (int) ( Math.random() * wlen2 );
            int rand3 = (int) ( Math.random() * wlen3 );

            String phrase = " " + wordlistone[rand1] + wordlisttwo[rand2] + wordlisttre[rand3] ;
            System.out.println("The Result is --->" + phrase );
    }
}
```

I was able to compile the code using javac phraseomatic.java command, and everything was good but when i run the code by using command java phraseomatic, I got the following output or errors, please let me know whether I am doing it right or my code is worng or both...? Thanks in advance. The errors is as below :

```
 root@ubuntu:~/java# java phraseomatic 


     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: phraseomatic :       Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
```

Answer (score 1):

The java `version` during compiling the code is different during running.Mean compiled with higher version than running version of JAVA.Make sure the version of running jvm is lower than compiled version.

Comment: so how to i correct the java version

Comment: Which version you are using during compile and running ?

Comment: how do i check the version during compile and running..?

Comment: java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.5) (6b24-1.11.5-0ubuntu1~12.04.1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)

Comment: so i think runtime is higher version. am i right..?

Comment: may b or you are using some api of higher java version.

Comment: ok so how do i correct that...?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46808/discussion-between-niks-tyagi-and-trilok-m)

Answer (score 1):

java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError is occur in below case 
Thrown when the Java Virtual Machine attempts to read a class file and determines that the major and minor version numbers in the file are not supported.

So you need to change your compiler to running version of java...
It's better go to Update one like java7

Comment: i checked with java -version and i got the version as java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.5) (6b24-1.11.5-0ubuntu1~12.04.1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
 so i guess runtime version is higher than compiler. so what do you suggest..?

Comment: Update the JDK  to 1.7..

Comment: Is you run time is 1.7 or 1.8?
As a simple Line. You can download update version of java and install.

Comment: @Jani why to update java. wht the issue with current version

Comment: @NiksTyagi, I know there is other way to correct this issue but this is the best way to solve issue without more information. It's easy as per my understand.